# Cannot dynamically reference name of view controller

Tags: swift

When instantiateViewController I would like to dynamically reference the class the storyboard identifier is paired with based on a conditional. I am able to pass the String name of the image literal when instantiating but not the viewController swift class? The error I get is `Cannot find type 'viewControllers' in scope`

**For example:**

```
var tabImage: String?
var viewControllers: UIViewController?


let tabBarController = CBFlashyTabBarController()

tabBarController.viewControllers = filteredNavigation.map { arrayProperty -> UIViewController in

if (arrayProperty.navname == "View1") {
   print("View1")
   tabImage = "tab1"
   viewControllers = ViewController1
}
else if (arrayProperty.navname == "View2") {
   print("View2")
   tabImage = "tab2"
   viewControllers = ViewController2
}
```

**Then I can pass the results of the conditional when instantiating:**

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(arrayProperty.navigationid)) as! viewControllers
controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
controller.navigationItem.title = arrayProperty.navname
controller.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: arrayProperty.navname, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: tabImage!), tag: 0)
controllerArray.append(controller)
return controller
```

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699454/instantiating-view-controllers-dynamically-swift). Instead, edit the previous one, and put it in a better share to be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(arrayProperty.navigationid)) as! viewControllers
```

Swift needs to assign a type, at compile time, to the variable `controller`.  That type needs to be unambiguous.

The value on the right side of `as!` must be a type name.  Here you've given a variable (so its not a type name - precisely what the error message is telling you) and you seem to be expecting to change that value at runtime, when the type must be determined at compile time.

In short, what you are trying to do cannot be done that way.

What's more, this code is not going to compile:

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController {
}

var viewControllers : UIViewController?

viewControllers = ViewController1
```

This declares `viewControllers` to be a reference (an Optional reference) to an *instance* of `UIViewController`.  `ViewController1` is a *class*, not an *instance* so this will generate a compiler error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController1.Type' to type
> 'UIViewController'

Comment: Is there a different way you would recommend to achieve the same result?

Comment: What problem are you having if you simply leave off `as! viewControllers` altogether?